# How to calculate SIM GPRS data which is uploaded by Quectel M66 during GET method?

Tags: iot, gsm, gprs, quectel

I am using Quectel M66 module to send data to web server using GET method. I am uploading data every minute using two APIs. I am using airtel SIM which consumes 2MB of data per hour as per shown in my airtel app. So I want to calculate how much data is actually uploaded by GSM module M66 ?

Thanks in advance.